# Angular2 redux: how to define store within the reducers

Tags: angular, redux, react-redux

I am coming from the react-redux world and have taken a angular project.

Is it possible to access the redux store the way you can do in react.

What I mean by this is if I can define small chunks of the store in the reducer declarations then access that part via some reference to that reducer? This way its easier to follow and understand the implementation later  when the app gets bigger

In every tutorial that i went trough the store was modeled/implemented as this single, big class that was passed to the entire application.

Comment: You can check this http://rahulrsingh09.github.io/WordMeaning/ngrx might help . Please pardon if it is of no use it has links to few apps made by me using redux

Comment: Have a look at this [**medium blog**](https://medium.com/@aravindfz/setting-up-storemodule-in-ngrx-4-0-b7c60732aa64)